# Which Dark Events take priority over others?

Tags: xcom-2

There's numerous kinds of Dark Events in game that can be set upon you.   I've seen some seemingly normal and not so impactful events, like Rural Checkpoints or making the cost of recruits a little bit more expensive for the duration of the month, but I'm curious if there's a list of which Dark Events are the most important to counter ASAP as opposed to other Dark Events?

Comment: I don't think there's going to be a strict ordering where specific ones are more important all the time. It's going to depend on your circumstances at the time. The one that makes recruits more expensive is irrelevant if you have enough recruits, but could be devastating if you've just had several casualties. Might be more useful to ask for a list of all the event types, and what might make each one critical.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's some game killers, ones that come to mind are raising Intel costs by 100%, 2 weeks progress to Advent facility, or adding progress to avatar project

Comment: This feels very opinion-based to me. I don't really agree with the rankings you've provided in your answer, because it heavily depends on your playstyle. For example, even on Commander/Legend, I love extra pods (more experience) and pay almost no attention to the Avatar progress because it's so easy to knock back down.

Answer (score 6):

After playing through this game on a Commander/Ironman run and struggling many times to prioritize Dark Events in which some basically ended my runs, I came up with a few events that I found to be more important than others.

Ordered from most lethal to least:

- Chryssalids on every mission

  - There's nothing worse when a trooper is caught offguard by an unactivated Chryssalid pod that activates as soon as you end your turn.   Having Chryssalids on every mission can be very dangerous as keeping a healthy top tier squad is a priority for most runs as the enemies only get tougher as time goes on.
- Avatar breakthroughs

  - When you have many missions to go through, adding progress to the Avatar bar can be a killer; especially if you don't have resistance comms in areas with ADVENT Blacksites
- Vigilance

  - 100% increase in intel costs for the entire month; Intel takes a while to build up and is used in almost many other things like research, Black Market, Resistance Comms, so keeping your Intel well stocked can be the difference between the loss of an entire run and winning the game.
- Show Of Force

  - Adding more enemies means more chances your squad can get hurt
- Rural Checkpoints

  - Reduces supplies of next Supply Drop by 50%
- Rapid Response

  - Show Of Force, but only on Guerilla Ops missions; same logic, more pods = more chances to maim or kill your squad members
- Anything Else

Comment: Need a description of the event for the ones identified by title. If one of those is reinforcements on every mission, then that seems wrong to include. I always ignore that one. Reinforcements are free xp. They drop in after you already know where, and trigger all your overwatch shots.

Comment: @DCShannon I'm not sure what difficulty you're playing on, but having too many pods can be a killer in some maps, like time based VIP extraction, retaliation missions, or terminal hacking. There are some enemy dark events that are immensely helpful, such as Faceless in every mission, as Faceless are your only source of Mimic Beacons.

Comment: Currently playing Commander Ironman

Comment: It's one thing to get flanked by a pod, but having extra pods adds more risk for your team especially when the game wants you to play aggresively.

Comment: *"advent equipped with poison rounds"* seemed like one you'd like to avoid. More enemies on one side is more problems, but also more opportunity to level up.

Comment: Isn't Vigilance the one that increases detection range? The intel cost one is Alien Cypher, and IIRC, it doesn't affect the black market. I think one of the devs mentioned that it doesn't affect facility leads, either; does any other research cost intel? I didn't pay much attention to research costs.